# MVC3 - Debugging the controller action called by an Ajax call

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio-debugging

I am attempting to populate a dropdown based on the value selected in another dropdown.  I am using [this guy's](http://blog.goranobradovic.com/2011/06/asp-net-mvc3-app-part-3-ajax-cascading-dropdownunobtrusive-version/) example, but have not gotten it to run successfully yet.  I have a successful Ajax call that is fired on the change event of the parent dropdown.  I've verified that the data passed to the Ajax function is correct.  However, the result is an error (200; unexpected character in JSON result).  I've been trying to figure out how to debug the a) controller action that is called in the Ajax call and b) the function that feeds a list of results to the controller action.  Can anybody help me figure out how to debug a) and b)?  Visual Studio 2010 doesn't offer a lot of help for debugging the targets of Ajax calls, it seems.

Here's the code I have:

1) The controller action (BreedController) that calls a list helper class function to supposedly return a JSON object back to the Ajax successful callback.

```
    //
    // Retrieve JSON object containing breeds for a given species
    //
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult BreedsBySpecies(int? id)
    {
        ListHelper lh = new ListHelper();
        return Json(new { items = lh.GetBreedsBySpecies(id) }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

2) The function that should return a SelectItemList of breeds given a species ID.  This is called by the controller action.

```
    public List<SelectListItem> GetBreedsBySpecies(int? speciesID)
    {

        var breed = from b in db.Breeds
                    select b;

        if (speciesID.HasValue)
        {
            breed = breed.Where(b => b.SpeciesID == speciesID);
        }

        List<SelectListItem> lst = new List<SelectListItem>();
        foreach (var item in breed)
        {
            lst.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = item.Description, Value = item.BreedID.ToString() });
        }

        return lst;
    }
```

3) The javascript function that does the Ajax call.  I've confirmed that this is getting the right values (e.g., "/Breed/BreedsBySpecies" to get to the right controller action and formData contains the right species ID)

```
function selectFromAjax(url, formData, target) {
    $(target).html("");
    if (formData.id) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: url,
            data: formData,
            dataType: 'text json',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            success: function (data, textStatus) {
                if (data) {
                    $(data.items).each(function () {
                        $(target).append($("<option></option>").attr("value", this.Value).text(this.Text));
                    });
                    $(target).change();
                }
            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                alert(xhr.status);
                alert(thrownError);
            }
        });
    }
    else {
        $(target).change();
    }
}
```

Comment: I installed firebug, but I don't see how that will let me debug VS2010 code?  How would I do that?

Comment: open the website and firebug. Refresh the website and in firebug click console to see the errors. It should show you the error. If not, go to scripts tab and find your file and code there. You can create breakpoints and debug your javascript there too.

Comment: That shows me that the Ajax error callback is being triggered, but it doesn't get me into the C# code at all.  As far as I can tell, the Ajax call is working as expected.  It's the C# code I'm trying to debug, but breakpoints on it aren't being hit.

Comment: try removing the success and failure from your ajax call, then It should come up with an error, and when you click on it and select html, it will show you the error page, just like regular asp.net error page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you should hit the break point if its making it that far.  my guess is that you need to stringify your object to get the json .net is going to understand.  or, since its such a simple object, just do something like:

```
 data: "{'id': '" + formData.Id + "'}"
```

### Edit

since you are just passing in an id, you could technically just use the url to get where you want, passing no data at all.  you'd just do something like this:

```
url: url + '/'+ formData.Id
```

this does tightly couple your routes and javascript, which isn't ideal, but it gets the job done. and it removes the need to pass any data to the data parameter.

Comment: I've tried breakpoints in both the controller action and the list helper function, but it never hits either.  I assumed (uh oh, there's that word again), that it was because the controller action is being called in the context of an Ajax call.  Should a breakpoint in the controller action or helper function be hit regardless?

Comment: @NealHelman, yes.  the issue is that the method is not being called due to the mvc modelbinder not being able to parse your json into something that you have a method signature for. i've actually thought of a simpler alternative that will work for these simple one parameter id things.  see my answer.

Comment: Thanks for that.  That gets me on to the next step, although I still can't tell what is going on in the controller action and helper function, which are really what I need to be looking at.

Comment: I got to debug the VS2010 code.  I'm such a dumb@55.  I had an AuthorizeAttribute on the controller that was being called.  Simplifying the ajax call seemed to be what I needed to be able to tell what was going on.

Comment: Had same issue and it turned out I accidentally had a controller action marked for private, so the AJAX call wasn't seeing it. Just something else to check if the breakpoint's never being hit.